# MacBook (SSD + FileVault) doesn't restore after battery depletion

Tags: ssd, battery, macbook-pro, hibernate, filevault

**Setup:** I have a MacBook Pro 15", mid 2009, 3.06GHz. The DVD drive has been replaced with a SAMSUNG SSD (830 series), 128GB, the battery has been replaced once with an original one. RAM was upgraded to 8GB.
The system is installed on the SSD, the HDD is mounted as my user directory. Both drives have encryption: FileVault is turned on for the SSD, while the HDD is unlocked by [this nice tool](https://github.com/jridgewell/Unlock) at boot.

**Issue:** When the battery reaches 0%, the computer hibernates to disk. When I reboot it, I am prompted for my password by FileVault, which displays an orange tick logo near to my user picture, to mark that there is a suspended session; I enter my (correct) password, and instead of logging into my session, **I get a quick blank screen and a reboot**.

**What I tried so far:**

- SMC and PVRAM reset.
- Changing `hibernatemode` via `pmset -a` into modes 0, 3, 25: works always fine when I issue a manual sleep/hibernation, but it doesn't work when battery dies.
- Deleting the `sleepimage` file.
- Changing `hibernatefile` to force storage in SSD first and then HDD.
- Checking `system.log` for suspicious messages.

**Other symptoms:**

- When hibernating manually, system log reports:
  `kernel[0]: WARNING: hibernate_page_list_setall skipped 6894 xpmapped pages`
  where the number 6894 changes from one test to another.
- I also get
  `kernel[0]: Sleep failure code 0x00000000 0x1f006a00`
- I can't find any `hibernate_*` related message in the system log at the time of power loss, nor any error message related to the failed restore from the sleep image, there is just the `Darwing Kernel Version...` from the *second* boot.
- I have 8GB of RAM but *the sleep image file is always 4GB*.

I tried to google all these symptoms but I found nothing that could help.

**My suspictions:**
[pmset's man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pmset.1.html) states that the sleep image file may only point to a file located on the root volume. My root volume is technically the SSD drive, but it's not physically located where Apple would expect the root volume to be (i.e. the HDD bay). *Can this be the reason why it can't load the sleep image?*
Of course any sleep image stored in the HDD wouldn't be accessible because at that stage FileVault can unlock only the root volume.
If that's not the case, *why is the sleep image file only 4GB?* I mean, *exactly* 4GB.

**More information:**
I've had this problem since when I added the SSD drive, from Lion to Yosemite. Unfortunately I didn't have the chance of testing the same situation without FileVault. RAM is healthy afaik.

**The questions:**
The situation is particular because of the SSD + FileVault setup, but the problem is surely related to the system being installed on a "secondary" drive. Is there any way to get the system restore to work properly in this context? What does exactly Apple mean by "root drive"? Why doesn't FileVault load properly my session, even though (sleep image size apart) it's stored correctly? Are the sleep failure code or the 4GB sleep image file meaningful in any way?

Any suggestion, clarification on Apple's internals, conjecture is well accepted!

Answer (score 0):

About the 4Gb sleepimage size: A [change](https://twitter.com/schwa/status/392880747922477056) in Mavericks appears to have been that the sleepimage is dynamically updated depending on the amount of RAM in use. So I don't think that is a problem.

When I did a similar thing on my 2010 17" MBP, I replaced the original system disk with the SSD (new system disk), and put the original system disk into the DVD bay. I don't have that setup any more but IIRC I used FileVault on that with no problems.

Comment: I kept my main HDD in the same position, so I could have the SMS working on the right disk. Now I wonder why does it even detect the suspended session.